# UIAppearance bug during state restoration

Tags: ios, ios11, uiappearance, ios12, state-restoration

## Update

Matt rightly pointed out that my original project had an error with state restoration. However, even after it is removed, I am able to reproduce an issue as long as I am using a table view inside a navigation controller and trying to set `isTranslucent` property of `UINavigationBar` to `false` via an appearance proxy.

---

For some reason, when iOS restores state, UIAppearance overrides values set in `viewDidLoad`. It causes me a lot of headaches, and I would like to know how to solve this issue. I view it as a bug.

[Here](https://github.com/AndriyGo/appearanceError) is a small project I created on GitHub to illustrate this issue. When you launch it for the first time, the label's font in `ViewController` is correctly set to 22 points. However, if you trigger state restoration, it will be 12 points because of the appearance method in `willFinishLaunching`.

In fact, the cause of this issue is not `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITableViewCell.self]).font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)` as I originally thought. Instead, `UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [GLXNavigationController.self]).isTranslucent = false` causes such a behaviour. You can easily verify it yourself.

One way to solve this is to set the font again in `layoutSubviews` because appearance proxies are applied just before `layoutSubviews` is called. However, I do not like this approach.

Another possible solution is to set `isTranslucent` manually for each navigation controller. It is a solution I am opting for, but I still feel that there is a bug with appearance proxy. At a minimum, we should expect consistent behaviour between initial launch and state restoration.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This might not fix it, but you should probably have no `didFinishLaunching` at all, and also it is crucial that `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` appear explicitly in `willFinishLaunching`.

Comment: @matt, you are a genius. Moving `makeKeyAndVisible` solves it. My logic behind placing it in `didFinishLaunching` was that if `ViewController` is restored, we do not need to set it. Otherwise, if no state restoration occurs, we need to set it.

Comment: @matt what would be your suggestion about what should reside in `willFinishLaunching` and what should go to `didFinishLaunching`? I am struggling with this a bit. All my UI is instantiated programatically

Comment: I really should have mentioned `makeKeyAndVisible` in my answer; I'll amend it. — If you're doing state saving and restoration, everything should reside in `willFinishLaunching` as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: By the way, all of this is in my book; the basic storyboard-based example is here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p341SimplestRestorationExample/ch19p652SimplestRestorationExample/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: @matt thank you very much! Should I call makeKeyAndVisible even if I am using storyboards? I didn't know it... Also, I assume that I could put initialisation of various 3rd party frameworks (eg firebase) in `didFinishLaunching`.

Comment: "Should I call makeKeyAndVisible even if I am using storyboards" Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing state restoration wrong:

- Change `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.
- And make sure that `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` contains a call to the window to `makeKeyAndVisible`, even if it contains nothing else.

That, along with implementations of `shouldSaveApplicationState` and `shouldRestoreApplicationState`, constitutes the rock-bottom boilerplate needed for *any* implementation of state saving and restoration.

Comment: Thank you very much, it does fix the issue in the trial project. However, in the real one, I also had to remove the line `UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [GLXNavigationController.self]).isTranslucent = false`. I am totally puzzled by why it is the case. However, I cannot reproduce this issue on a small project...

Comment: Bingo! I was able to reproduce it on a small project. Will post an update now